# Kotlin - Return a Boolean from an async task that does not return a boolean

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin

I'm attempting to return a boolean from the following function. app.loginAsync returns another object, and is not mine so I cannot change it. Is there a way that I can do this?

The app.loginAsync is a MongoDB Realm function.

```
fun login(email: String, password: String): Boolean {
    val credentials = Credentials.emailPassword(email, password)
    app.loginAsync(credentials) {
        if (!it.isSuccess) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t return the async result because it arrives some time in the future. You can either make your own function take a callback that you pass the Boolean to by calling it, or you can make this a suspend function and use suspendCoroutine to get the async result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CompletableDeferred. Try something like that:

```
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Boolean {
    val completableDeferred = CompletableDeferred<Boolean>() 
    val credentials = Credentials.emailPassword(email, password)
    app.loginAsync(credentials) {
        completableDeferred.complete(it.isSuccess)
    }
    return completableDeferred.await()
}
```